# i'm using ads within a uitableview, where every 4th item or so in the list is an ad

Tags: ios, position, tableview, ads

I'm using ads within a `UITableView`, where every 4th item or so in the list is an ad. It works but the ad takes the position of an object like  1-2-3-ad-5-6-7-ad not 1-2-3-ad-4-5-6-ad

My `UITableView` methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section==0)
    {
            return 0;
    }
    else{
        return [self.articlesArray count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (3 == (row % 4)) {  // or 0 == if you  want the first cell to be an ad!
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"AdCell";
        AdViewCell  *cell = (AdViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass: AdViewCell.class] {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AdCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell = [[AdViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
        }
        GADBannerView *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeMediumRectangle];

        bannerView =[[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width,heigth,300,250)];

        bannerView.adUnitID =@"";
        bannerView.rootViewController =self;
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        [bannerView loadRequest:request];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:bannerView];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
        ArticleViewCell *cell = (ArticleViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass: ArticleViewCell.class]))
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArticleCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
            cell = [[ArticleViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] ;
        }

        NSInteger offset = indexPath.row / 4;
        NSInteger roww = indexPath.row - offset;
        NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:roww];

        NSString *imageUrl = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"featured_image_thumbnail_tab_url"];
        imageUrl = [imageUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [cell.thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl ] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (image) {
            // Set your image over here
        }else{
            //something went wrong
            NSLog(@"Error occured : %@", [error description]);
        }
   }];

    NSString * title=[tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"title.rendered"];

    cell.titleLabel.text = title;

    NSString * excerpt=[tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"excerpt.rendered"];
    NSString *excerpt_rend =[self convertHTML:excerpt];
    cell.excerptLabel.text = excerpt_rend;

    return cell;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showarticle"]){
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 
   DGArticleViewController *articleViewController =    (DGArticleViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
   articleViewController.articlesDetails = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:rowww];  //rowww = roww
   NSLog(@"data article %@",articleViewController.articlesDetails);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce an offset of number of shown ads:

```
NSInteger offset = indexPath.row / 4
NSIngteger adjustedRow = indexPath.row - offset
// use row from adjustedRow, instead of indexPath.row
NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:adjustedRow];
...
NSString *imageUrl = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:adjustedRow]objectForKey:@"featured_image_thumbnail_tab_url"];
```

Also, `numberOfRowsInSection:`needs to be adjusted, otherwize you are missing items:

```
return [self.articlesArray count] + [self.articlesArray count] / 4;
```

And in `prepareForSegue`:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; 
NSInteger *adjusted = indexPath.row - indexPath.row / 4
...
articleViewController.articlesDetails = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:adjusted];
...
```

---

Test:

```
for (int testIndexPathRow = 0; testIndexPathRow < 100; ++testIndexPathRow) {
    if (3 == testIndexPathRow % 4) {
        NSLog(@"Ad");
    } else {
        NSInteger offset = testIndexPathRow / 4;
        NSInteger row = testIndexPathRow - offset;
        NSLog(@"data at index: %d", row);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
2016-11-11 12:09:16.927 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 0
2016-11-11 12:09:16.927 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 1
2016-11-11 12:09:16.927 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 2
2016-11-11 12:09:16.928 TEST[7126:382810] Ad
2016-11-11 12:09:16.928 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 3
2016-11-11 12:09:16.928 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 4
2016-11-11 12:09:16.928 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 5
2016-11-11 12:09:16.928 TEST[7126:382810] Ad
2016-11-11 12:09:16.928 TEST[7126:382810] data at index: 6
...
```

Comment: In your code: `[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` still uses `indexPath.row`instead of `roww`. Also, you are missing items, as `numberOfRowsInSection`returns not enough. Check/ take the code I edited for you. If it fails, explain din detailed what the issue is.

Comment: the issue is that i get i wrong index when getting data to detailsView

Comment: You should now be able to fix this yourself. If you can't, see update in my answer. That costs you an upvote :-)

Comment: Than pay your price :-)

Comment: Was just a joke. Newbee special welcome :-) Offtopic: If you are starting, start with Swift3 instead of Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the indexpath.row to reflect the skipped cells. So in your else part replace indexPath.row with adjustedRow number.

```
else
{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
ArticleViewCell *cell = (ArticleViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
if ((cell == nil) || (![cell isKindOfClass: ArticleViewCell.class]))
{
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ArticleCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
cell = [[ArticleViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                              reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier] ;
}

NSInteger adjustedRow = indexPath.row - indexPath.row/4;
NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:adjustedRow];

 NSString *imageUrl = [[self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:adjustedRow]objectForKey:@"featured_image_thumbnail_tab_url"];
 imageUrl = [imageUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 [cell.thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl ] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageRetryFailed completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
if (image){
    // Set your image over here
}else{
    //something went wrong
    NSLog(@"Error occured : %@", [error description]);
}
}];

NSString * title=[tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"title.rendered"];

cell.titleLabel.text = title;


NSString * excerpt=[tempDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"excerpt.rendered"];
NSString *excerpt_rend =[self convertHTML:excerpt];
cell.excerptLabel.text = excerpt_rend;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you have array with 8 rows and you also want 2 ads, means total 10 rows. But you are passing only array count that creates problem. To solve this follow below code

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if (section==0)
    {
       return 0;
    }
    else
    {

       return [self.articlesArray count] + ([self.articlesArray count]/4);
    }
}
```

Fetch data from array as given below, it will definitely helps you

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
       //Your current code
       int index = indexPath.row/4
       NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [self.articlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-index];

       //Your current code
}
```